# I want to execute a shell script on an Android device when it boots up

Tags: boot

I want to run a shell script on my Android device every time it boots.
What do I need to do?
The script is stored on the MMC of the device and looks like this:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
MUXPORT=`/system/bin/getprop hn.gsmux.port`
Modemport=`/system/bin/getprop hn.gsmmux.modem`
/system/bin/setprop hn.gsmmux.mux-exit""

/system/bin/log -t gsmmux "port: $MUXPORT"
/system/bin/log -t gsmmux "modemtype: modemport"

/system/bin/hn_gsmmux -p $MUXPORT -b 115200 -s/dev/hmmodemmux -m Modemport

/system/bin/setprop hn.gsmmux.mux-exit $?
#exit $?
```

Comment: You wanna look pretty hard at /init*rc

Comment: sir mikeserv can u expalin me how it can happen..? what to do ..any example

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: no root acess...

Comment: Then youll need to write a small android app - or possibly use an app that can do the equivalent for you, such as *`Tasker`* - that can become a service executed at startup. Without a scripting service like *`Tasker`* youll likely need to do it with Java.

Comment: bro the thing u saying and i asking is differanrt...look my android set is at lock condition..and i want to make a shell file which will run automatically when set got power on..how i can..?

Comment: I know what youre saying - at boot the Android system interprets and executes shell scripts and rules applied in /init*rc. Without root you cannot modify these files. So you have to compromise - either write an app that can get boot service permissions and have it execute your script or use one that already does and tell it to run your script. Thats what youre looking at. Sorry.

Comment: Unless you've installed some flavor of Linux for Android or other tools, your question is off-topic here. Android runs off a Linux kernel, but it doesn't have a full-blown unix system, and in particular it doesn't include any of the mechanisms that allow users to run code at boot time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android, not about a unix flavor.